# AJAX Transferring page PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web

This is the structure I have:

A router.php, based on $_POST['c'] generates the controller file name, includes the file and calls the $_POST['a'] method of it.

I have a gridview. The only way to open a details page when the user clicks the row is to use AJAX, since only javascript can handle the clicking. I don't want to have a button column - I want a row click.

So I have my javascript doing this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
$("tr" ).click(function() {

  var id = $('td[name=id]').attr('id');
  var c = $('input[name=c]').attr('value');
  var a = $('input[name=a]').attr('value');

      $.post("Router.php", { id: id, c: c, a: a }, function(data){
        window.location.href = "Router.php";
        });
    });
});
```

I have my Router.Php:

```
if (array_key_exists('c', $_POST)) {
        $controller = $_POST['c'];
    };

    if (array_key_exists('a', $_POST)) {
        $action = $_POST['a'];
    };

echo $controller; 
echo $action;
```

I can never get the post values. I think I'm thinking about AJAX wrong - what AJAX is suppose to do is to just get a response and render it somewhere on the browser. What I'm using it for is to pass POST data and call a method within a PHP file. The reason for this is because I don't want to pass the id in the url.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Do a `print_r` on your `$_POST` array; that will tell you what, if anything, is getting posted.

Answer (score 0):

The following part of your code issues 2 requests to the server. A POST and then a GET.

```
$.post("Router.php", { id: id, c: c, a: a }, function(data){
    window.location.href = "Router.php";
});
```

Most probably you are getting what you want on the first request, but the result that you see on your screen is the outcome of the second request, which is just a GET without params.

The result of the post is being written using `echo $controller;` and `echo $action;` and these are returned in `(data)` but you don't do anything with that. You just redirect the client to `Router.php`.

Comment: How can I pass POST parameters to Router.php and get it to use them to redirect to a method in Controller?

Comment: Because I think I know what is happening - 'data' is my whole page sent back to me. The problem I'm having - usually with AJAX people render stuff in a container. I want to use AJAX to actually simulate redirecting to another page. How would I do that?